# Drupal: Error Message when add new page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have new Drupal. I am not sure about Drupal work with add page, article or blog.

This error shows when I add new page click on "preview" button then click "save" button or click on delete link.

Here error message

> "The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or
>   you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result,
>   your changes cannot be saved."

Why Drupal not allow Save content after I preview?

Please kindly help with this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This message is caused when either (1) two users access the edit page and one user saves changes before the other user gets a chance or (2) when a user edits content, saves it, and clicks the back button to get back to the edit page.

**Solution:** From Home » Administration » Configuration » Development click on **Clear all caches** button.